# Java populating a 3D linked list with recursion

Tags: java, list, recursion, nodelist

I'm getting a stack overflow while trying to populate my 3D linked list. I don't understand why it's not stopping at the specified bounds, it just runs forever. It's probably a simple error, i just don't understand.

EDIT: Okay I have now updated the code and removed that silly mistake, however it's still not operating exactly as intended. It does seem to be generating the 10x10x10 list, however its running infinitely. Initialized with (10, 10, 10), it should create 10000 objects and stop. I'm just trying to create a list to represent a 3d coordinate plane and each integer coordinate is one node, accessible by direction pointer north, south, east, west, up, or down.

Any help appreciated

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeController3D con = new NodeController3D(6,6, 6);

    }

}
public class Node3D {

//    public Node3D(Node3D... nodes) {
//        if (nodes.length != 5) {
//            throw new RuntimeException();
//        }
//        this.nodes = nodes;
//    }

    public Node3D[] nodes;
    public int x, y, z;


    public Node3D north() {
        return nodes[0];
    }

    public Node3D south() {
        return nodes[1];
    }

    public Node3D east() {
        return nodes[2];
    }

    public Node3D west() {
        return nodes[3];
    }

    public Node3D up() {
        return nodes[4];
    }

    public Node3D down() {
        return nodes[5];
    }
}

public class NodeController3D {

    public NodeController3D(int length, int width, int height) {
        HEAD = new Node3D();
        pnc(HEAD, length, width, height);
    }

    private void pnc(Node3D node, int xMax, int yMax, int zMax) {
        if(node.nodes == null) {
            node.nodes = new Node3D[5];
        }

        if (node.x < xMax) {
            Node3D newNode = node.nodes[2] = new Node3D();
            newNode.x = node.x + 1;
            newNode.y = node.y;
            newNode.z = node.z;
            System.out.println(newNode.x + ", " + newNode.y + ", " + newNode.z);

            pnc(newNode, xMax, yMax, zMax);
        }
        if (node.y < yMax) {
            Node3D newNode = node.nodes[0] = new Node3D();
            newNode.x = node.x;
            newNode.y = node.y + 1;
            newNode.z = node.z;

            pnc(newNode, xMax, yMax, zMax);
        }
        if (node.z < zMax) {
            Node3D newNode = node.nodes[4] = new Node3D();
            newNode.x = node.x;
            newNode.y = node.y;
            newNode.z = node.z + 1;

            pnc(newNode, xMax, yMax, zMax);
        }
    }

//    public NodeController3D(int radius) {
//
//    }

    public final Node3D HEAD;
}
```

EDIT: Okay I have now updated the code and removed that silly mistake, however it's still not operating exactly as intended. It does seem to be generating the 10x10x10 list, however its running infinitely. Initialized with (10, 10, 10), it should create 10000 objects and stop. I'm just trying to create a list to represent a 3d coordinate plane and each integer coordinate is one node, accessible by direction pointer.

Comment: Paste your stack trace.

Comment: Updated. It repeats those two lines

Comment: the line numbers weren't corresponding due to removing packaging, i added the line numbers into the code for the offending lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into an infinite recursion.

So what is happening.

You are creating a new `Array`.

```
if(node.nodes == null) {
   node.nodes = new Node3D[5];
}
```

You go on by using a `Node3D` as a `newNode` variable. This happens because `node.x<xMax` will be true. -> `Node3D newNode = node.nodes[2] = new Node3D();`.

You recursivly call `pnc` now, with this `newNode`.

So what happens now, `node.y<yMax` will be true . 
Now you reassign the newNode. `Node3D newNode = node.nodes[0] = new Node3D();`. 
and call `pnc` recursivly again. But you are running into a problem now. since it is a new `Node3D` your `node.x<xMax` will be true again and these two steps are happening again and ininite until you are getting your mentioned error.

To fix this error you might want to copy `node.x` and `node.y` into your newly created variable.

By changing the assignment you could jump out of the infinite recursion.

```
if (node.x < xMax) {
    if (node.nodes[2] == null) {
        node.nodes[2] = new Node3D();
    }
    Node3D newNode = node.nodes[2];
    newNode.x = node.x + 1;
    newNode.y = node.y;
    newNode.z = node.z;

    pnc(newNode, xMax, yMax, zMax);
}
if (node.y < yMax) {
    if (node.nodes[0] == null) {
        node.nodes[0] = new Node3D();
    }
    Node3D newNode = node.nodes[0];
    newNode.x = node.x;
    newNode.y = node.y + 1;
    newNode.z = node.z;

    pnc(newNode, xMax, yMax, zMax);
}
if (node.z < zMax) {
    if (node.nodes[4] == null) {
        node.nodes[4] = new Node3D();
    }
    Node3D newNode = node.nodes[4];
    newNode.x = node.x;
    newNode.y = node.y;
    newNode.z = node.z + 1;

    pnc(newNode, xMax, yMax, zMax);
}
```

But since i don´t know what you are trying to achive with this specific elements at these specifics index in your array this might be a wrong solution for you.

Comment: Thanks you helped me fix part of it, but please see the updated question :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a new Node3D, the variables x, y and z are not initialized, therefore they will evaluate to 0 if accessed.

In the pnc method, there will always be cases where either x < xMax, y < yMax or z < zMax since those are all set to 1.

A good practice is to make variables private and final where possible:

```
class Node3D {
    private final Node3D[] nodes;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final int z;

    public Node3D(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.nodes = new Node3D[6];
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

This will prevent these kinds of errors in the future. You can create getter methods for the variables. If you really need to reassign the values for x, y or z, you could instead create a new Node3D so that the object can remain immutable.

Comment: Thanks you helped me fix part of it, but please see the updated question :)

Answer (score 1):

You were navigating to nodes in the 3D grid in multiple ways. For example, you went to (1,1,0) both from (1,0,0) and (0,1,0), creating duplicates for the same coordinate. This way, you create a number of nodes equal to the total sum of [cube paths](https://nrich.maths.org/606) for each node.

An other approach is to populate a cube of nodes, and give each node a reference to the cube that they are in. Then when you need to go North, you just let the cube return the right node, using the coordinates of the current node. You could use Apache's [MultiKeyMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html) as a grid:

```
class Node3D {
    private static int instances = 0;
    public final int x;
    public final int y;
    public final int z;
    public final int number;
    public final MultiKeyMap<Integer, Node3D> gridMap;

    public Node3D(MultiKeyMap<Integer, Node3D> gridMap, int x, int y, int z) {
        this.gridMap = gridMap;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.number = instances++;
    }

    //Add/alter these methods according to your orientation
    //Returns null if no value is present, you might want to handle this
    public Node3D getNorthNode() {
        return gridMap.get(this.x + 1, this.y, this.z);
    }

    //Other getters omitted

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node3D#" + number + "[" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + "]";
    }
}
```

Now initialization can be done as follows:

```
    MultiKeyMap<Integer, Node3D> gridMap = new MultiKeyMap<>();
    for(int x = 0; x < xMax; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < yMax; y++) {
            for(int z = 0; z < zMax; z++) {
                gridMap.put(x, y, z, new Node3D(gridMap, x, y, z));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(gridMap.get(4, 4, 4).getNorthNode());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however I was looking for a way to get around the speed limitations in maps. Is there no way to populate it closer to the original way but without following cube paths? I know you can fill a 2d array easily with nested loops, why not a 3d array?

Comment: Basically when you do it the other way, you'd have to register each newly created node with all of its potential neighbours, and register each neighbour with the newly created node. This will prevent creating duplicate nodes. But I think that approach would be much more tedious and error-prone.